# What is the equivalent for query_posts() in WP e-commerce

Tags: wordpress

I am using WP e-commerce for my worpress blog. I want to display a particular product in my template. I wrote the code like this.

```
          query_posts('p=186'); 
          while (wpsc_have_products()) :  wpsc_the_product(); 
                 echo wpsc_the_product_title();
                       ................
                       ................
          endwhile;
```

But it is not working. I think the problem is with query_posts(). Is there any equivalent function for query_posts or How can I display a product with it's id in WP e-commerce.

Answer (score 1):

See if it works for you:

```
$wpsc_query = new WPSC_query("category_id=3");
```